# 'GADInvalidInitializationException', reason: 'The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized without an application ID

Tags: ios, swiftui, admob, plist

enter code hereI know this is an old problem and saw previous responses and tried all steps;

- I successfully added Library using XCode packages and bot Pods both tried
- I added -ObjC to ALL linker flags including project level and target level
- I added Info.plist file as exactly suggested here https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start#update_your_infoplist and I have a published application but dont have an Admob account yet so I used this generic id. ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511
- I tried this key = GADIsAdManagerApp true.
- Even I just have import GoogleMobileAds, not added this still error GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)

I tried on real phone, but still I have same error, and I am working on it around a week, so all helps are appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.wowso.DataScienceInterviewQuiz</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>DailyDataScience Interview</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.1</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
    <string>ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>SKAdNetworkItems</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>4fzdc2evr5.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>4pfyvq9l8r.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>2fnua5tdw4.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>ydx93a7ass.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>5a6flpkh64.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>p78axxw29g.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>v72qych5uu.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>ludvb6z3bs.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>cp8zw746q7.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>3sh42y64q3.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>c6k4g5qg8m.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>s39g8k73mm.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>3qy4746246.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>f38h382jlk.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>hs6bdukanm.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>v4nxqhlyqp.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>wzmmz9fp6w.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>yclnxrl5pm.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>t38b2kh725.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>7ug5zh24hu.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>gta9lk7p23.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>vutu7akeur.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>y5ghdn5j9k.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>n6fk4nfna4.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>v9wttpbfk9.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>n38lu8286q.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>47vhws6wlr.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>kbd757ywx3.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>9t245vhmpl.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>eh6m2bh4zr.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>a2p9lx4jpn.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>22mmun2rn5.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>4468km3ulz.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>2u9pt9hc89.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>8s468mfl3y.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>klf5c3l5u5.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>ppxm28t8ap.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>ecpz2srf59.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>uw77j35x4d.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>pwa73g5rt2.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>mlmmfzh3r3.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>578prtvx9j.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>4dzt52r2t5.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>e5fvkxwrpn.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>8c4e2ghe7u.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>zq492l623r.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>3rd42ekr43.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>3qcr597p9d.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
        <string>Icon-App-20x20@2x</string>
        <string>Icon-App-20x20@3x</string>
        <string>Icon-App-29x29@2x</string>
        <string>Icon-App-29x29@3x</string>
        <string>Icon-App-40x40@2x</string>
        <string>Icon-App-40x40@3x</string>
        <string>Icon-App-60x60@2x</string>
        <string>Icon-App-60x60@3x</string>
        <string>Icon-76@2x.png</string>
        <string>Icon-83.5@2x.png</string>
        <string>Icon-1024.png</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

[image: -ObjC Target Level]
[image: -ObjC Project Level]

Comment: It seems like your ID is incorrect. Can you show the plist file or the line on plist file for `GADApplicationIdentifier`.

Comment: I’m pretty sure Google requires that the app be live before authorizing ads. Once the app is live you’ll get an AppStore ID that get loaded into the website. You also need an admob account.

Comment: Thanks for responses, as far as I see without Admob account using test IDs, it should work, and I added the plist file, I am using GoogleAdmob trial id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after working on this error more than one week, I found reason and want to share here. In Targets - Build Settings - Packaging there is Generate Info.plist file, it was yes, I made it to No and problem gone :). I hope it will help to someone else also.